# NSURLSession - Random crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlsession

I am trying to download  100 file in background using `NSURLSession`. (Modified Apple's sample code - SimpleBackgroundTransfer). In iPhone i am getting the following logs

```
nsnetworkd[298] <Error>: Canceling SSDownload: <SSDownload: 0x15ee62760>: -9205186979102545636 (task (null)) since it's not associated with a task or the phase is not SSDownloadPhaseDownloading

 mstreamd[335] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: Not monitoring for external power.
 mstreamd[335] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon stopping.
 mstreamd[335] <Notice>: (Note ) AS: <MSIOSAlbumSharingDaemon: 0x15ee18bb0>: Shared Streams daemon has shut down.
 mstreamd[335] <Notice>: (Warn ) mstreamd: mstreamd shutting down.
 mstreamd[336] <Notice>: (Note ) mstreamd: mstreamd starting up.
 mstreamd[336] <Notice>: (Note ) PS: Media stream daemon starting...
```

Sometimes the iPhone crashed due to low memory warning and 
`springBoard`, `backboardd`, `nsnetworkd` were showed as largest process each time. Do anyone faced this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You have not shown any code. do you start all 100 downloads at the same time on background threads? If so don't, schedule only a few at a time.

Comment: @Zaph Yes, i am adding all the items as an array. But one 3 files will be downloaded at a time. Downloading starts when the app goes background. In some other post i read that it is good to give entire items to download at once.